# RHEL reposync, management interface?

Tags: rhel, package-management, repository

I am looking to configure reposync for a linux estate on RHEL and was wandering if anyone knew if a web-interface plugin of sorts exists to manage it?

As a reference point, something similar to WSUS on Windows, or Plesk for a LAMP stack. I've been hunting through Github and haven't found anything yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you look into Spacewalk ?
http://spacewalk.redhat.com

It's the redhat satellite but free :)

I used it and it was easy to use when you have configured whole the system.

Comment: I'll take a look, it looks like it will do exactly what I need and more. Thanks.